# Get system config data in custom module

Tags: magento2, module, email-templates, system.xml

I've seen a couple of things about this but I can't seem to get the value

I have

```
<field id="template" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="3" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
      <label>Email Template</label>
      <source_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Email\Template</source_model>
      <config_path>cron/email/template</config_path>
</field>
```

I want to get the email selected in that field, so I created a Helper Data.php with

```
    /*
     * @return string
     */
    public function getTemplate($scope = ScopeConfigInterface::SCOPE_TYPE_DEFAULT)
    {
        return $this->scopeConfig->getValue(
            'cron/email/template',
            $scope
        );
    }
```

Then I have a cron that runs another helper that looks like

```
<?php
namespace Custom\OrderCancelled\Helper;

use Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context;
use Magento\Framework\Translate\Inline\StateInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Escaper;
use Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder;
use Custom\OrderCancelled\Helper\Data;

class Email extends \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper
{
    protected $inlineTranslation;
    protected $escaper;
    protected $transportBuilder;
    protected $logger;
    protected $helper;

    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        StateInterface $inlineTranslation,
        Escaper $escaper,
        TransportBuilder $transportBuilder,
        Data $helper
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->inlineTranslation = $inlineTranslation;
        $this->escaper = $escaper;
        $this->transportBuilder = $transportBuilder;
        $this->helper = $helper;
        $this->logger = $context->getLogger();
    }

    public function sendEmail()
    {
      $templatetest = $this->helper->getTemplate();

      $writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/OrderCancelled.log');
      $logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
      $logger->addWriter($writer);
      $logger->info('||' . $templatetest . '||');
    }
}
```

But the $templatetest returns empty.
What's wrong here?

Thanks :D

Comment: can you check template field value save in database, which value store in core_config_data table and check path is cron/email/template ?

Comment: It is 9, I changed and got it working but I think ir ends in the same so idk why this didn't work and the other way did, I'll post in an answer the way it worked

Answer (score 0):

So I got it working just changing this

```
$templatetest = $this->helper->getTemplate();
```

To this

```
$templatetest = $this->helper->getConfig('cron/email/template');
```

And this

```
/*
 * @return string
 */
public function getTemplate($scope = ScopeConfigInterface::SCOPE_TYPE_DEFAULT)
{
    return $this->scopeConfig->getValue(
        'cron/email/template',
        $scope
    );
}
```

to this

```
public function getConfig($config_path)
    {
        return $this->scopeConfig->getValue(
            $config_path,
            \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE
        );
    }
```

But surely I can't understand why the way I did returned empty and the other returned the right value.

EDIT:
This is the system.xml

```
<system>
    <tab id="cron" translate="label" sortOrder="1000">
        <label>Crons</label>
    </tab>
    <section id="cron" translate="label" sortOrder="10" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
        <label>Emails</label>
        <tab>cron</tab>
        <resource>Crons_SystemConfig::cron</resource>
        <group id="general" translate="label" sortOrder="10" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
            <label>Order Cancelled</label>
            <field id="template" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="3" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                <label>Email Template</label>
                <source_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Email\Template</source_model>
                <config_path>cron/email/template</config_path>
            </field>
        </group>
    </section>
</system>
```

Thanks :D

Comment: Can you share your system.xml file where you defined cron/email/template value

Comment: Check the edit, thanks :D

Comment: please add config.xml code as well

Comment: I do not have a config.xml, should I? I'm kinda new to this but since it is working I thought I didn't need it

Comment: yes you need it..

Comment: Okay but why do I need it? What will it do? Sorry if I missed something it will add the default value right? I'm not using the default and that's why it is working is that it?

Answer (score 0):

Can you check following blog ..

To add config path  ?

https://inviqa.com/blog/how-use-system-configuration-and-helpers-magento-2

If any more help required let me know.

Comment: I used that as example but why do I need the config.xml? What will it do? Since I can get the selected admin option the way I showed in my answer, sorry if I missed something.
Thanks :D

Comment: check if it exist in core_config_data for cron/email/template ?

Comment: It does, with the ID of the template it's selected in this case it is 9. The config will only add the default right?